# How make KDE shift + numpad home key to work selecting text?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, kde

I've just migrated from GNOME 3.

I want to press shift and numpad home key and select text until the begin of the line.

The behaviour I see is: when I press shift, if numlock is on, it works like home and cursor go to the begin of the line but not selecting text.

If numlock is off and I press shift it just prints 7.
It's like "shift" is just doing the opposite of numlock.
What I want is to, with numlock off, I press shift + 7 numpad key (home) it select my text from cursor to the begin of the line. 
I want the same behaviour to "end/1 keypad".

In my research there was an option to "work like MS Windows" but it doesn't show here. I'm with KDE 5.15.4.

It's the same as here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1496421

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue. After checking checkbox shown in the picture, it is working as expected.

[image: Kde's keyboard config]

Comment: Thanks much! Saved me from this boring issue! :)

Answer (score 2):

The above menu could be obtained via `Tweaks` App in Ubuntu 22

Comment: Note: Tweaks offers a search function but it can't find it. However, the option is still there: [ Keyboard & Mouse › Additional Layout Options › Compatibility Options ]